# How to express "At least one of the exisiting properties AND no additional properties" with a mapped type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

please forgive me the slightly longish title.

given the following type

```
type A = {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
    baz: boolean;
}
```

I like to create a new "partial" type B

```
type B = Partial<A>
```

such that B must contain at least one of the properties of A and only properties of A are allowed

```
//compiles
const b1 = {
   foo: "yeah"
}

//errors
const b2 = {}
const b3 = {lala: "lala"}
const b4 = {foo: "foo is alowed", but_not_this: false}
```

Comment: Note that "and no other properties" is always subject to Typescript's excess property checking mechanism.

Comment: @robkuz, don't think I forgot your awesome articles https://robkuz.github.io/Higher-kinded-types-in-fsharp-Intro-Part-I/

Comment: @captain-yossarian oh, this is very kind of you. And your answer here is at least equally awesome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
type A = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  baz: boolean;

}
type AtLeastOne<Obj, Keys = keyof Obj> = Keys extends keyof Obj ? Pick<Obj, Keys> : never

type NonEmpty<T> = Partial<T> & AtLeastOne<T>

// Partial<A> & (Pick<A, "foo"> | Pick<A, "bar"> | Pick<A, "baz">)
type Result = NonEmpty<A>

//compiles
const b1: Result = {
  foo: "yeah"
}

//errors
const b2: Result = {}
const b3: Result = { lala: "lala" }
const b4: Result = { foo: "foo is alowed", but_not_this: false }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFKAzA9jgXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmA3OpgEYCGphlArgLaMSn0YoLAF6FGeADYRmlAegC%206UJFjAAMtJIB5ShAA8WxgCsANFADSEEEQRQA1lZxYohowD5bl61AgAPYBCUACY2DiBOLsZQAPxQAArkAMZ2BsZmXkQe7BAAbnzoSuDQAHI4lACiXGCgegAqHohxrMDkzBJ1HgBkqhrM2rodBWgA9MPxza3tMF1QABQJyXowZgBEuDgrHgA%208Ukpy1ArLKSbUDsL%206simwCUhSoAShBEHBLAtqUVVTXTQ6OJOCq5CkRHQAMoJCEAEZCE8Xm9bKhBOtCCsQNIABYrBR-YZ8Ug4UigtDgyGMABMsOer3eiCQihJZTJAGYqfDacgoBI2sxUdzuSsoAzSe9GAAWNk0xHYPCo9ZQcg2No4ADuECCKzMjA4wAA%20pQcHrgBjFYQsG0iNB5EA)

**Explanation**

`Partial<A> & Pick<A, "foo"> | Pick<A, "bar"> | Pick<A, "baz">` this is minimum required type you should end up.

First of all we need to make sure that object is not empty. It should have either of three props.

Consider [distributive-conditional-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

```js
type AtLeastOne<Obj, Keys = keyof Obj> = Keys extends keyof Obj ? Pick<Obj, Keys> : never
```

According to the docs, `Pick<Obj, Keys>` - will be applied to each key. Hence, `AtLeastOne` returns `Pick<A, "foo"> | Pick<A, "bar"> | Pick<A, "baz">`.

Now the easiest part, you need just use intersection in order to merge return type of `AtLeastOne` and `Partial<A>`

```js
type NonEmpty<T> = Partial<T> & AtLeastOne<T>
```

More interesting examples you will find in my typescript [blog](https://catchts.com/)