# Typescript Type 'never': how to use for object fields?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62163715/349169) to work like [this](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=16&ssc=27&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHJwBcyIArgLYBG0A3PodaQM5hSgDmDhyCp1TABsIcEAwC+uXGACeABxQBRAB7yh6ACYQAPABUAfMgC8yANYRZ6GMj3IIKyCE0tkoGNGQBpRgQD83vaOEM6u5CBmIOgA7iC+yAHYyADaAJJuIOaW1rYAuqTpDk4ugQF6abnIpCAQAG6eUrzVddDxzfVQDNJyirYQbCbIqupauhjoBl0I6CADkGykev1gg9gkyACMEgxAA):

```
interface Foo {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
}

type Explode<T> = keyof T extends infer K
    ? K extends unknown
    ? { [I in keyof T]: I extends K ? T[I] : never }
    : never
    : never;


type Test = Explode<Foo>;

const test: Test = {a: 1};
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: number; b: never; c: never; } | { a: never; b: string; c: never; } | { a: never; b: never; c: boolean; }'.
  Type '{ a: number; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ a: number; b: never; c: never; }': b, c
```

How can I instantiate an object of type `Test` without the error? I want a type that can contain either field `a` or `b` or `c` (or be an empty `{}`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to express "At least one of the exisiting properties AND no additional properties" with a mapped type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69246630/how-to-express-at-least-one-of-the-exisiting-properties-and-no-additional-prope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I needed to make `Foo`s fields optional like this:

**EDITED** to include the suggestion by @apokryfos

```
interface Foo {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
}
```

Now I can do:

```
interface Foo {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
}

type AtMostOneOf<T> = keyof T extends infer K
    ? K extends unknown
    ? { [I in keyof T]+?: I extends K ? T[I] : never }
    : never
    : never;


type Test = AtMostOneOf<Foo>;

const test: Test = {a: 1}; // allowed
const test1: Test = {b: 'asd'}; // allowed
const test2: Test = {a: 1, b: 'asd'}; // not allowed
const test3: Test = {} // allowed
```

[Playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.3.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHJwBcyIArgLYBG0A3PodaQM5hSgDmDhyCp1TABsIcEAwC+uXGACeABxQBBMAFl0bAPIgImmAB4AKgD5kAXmQBrCLPQxkh5BAAekEABMWyUDGjIA0owEAPwBTq4QHl7kIJYg6ADuIEHIodjIANoAkt4gVjZ2DgC6ANTBpDkubp5hoYbZRcikOgBuflK8zRBtUCldPQzScooOEGzmyCrqWjp6+hjoxoMI6CDjkGykhmNgE9gkyACMEnTIAPRnREJCiRDuuCtruxtgh1s7e8zIAORwLO7fE7nS5wa63e6PdY7ABM73GFn2pEOABpkF9fv9AacLmR0LtQTcEncHqsoWwAMxw3YIiTAq6E4lAA)

Comment: You don't need to make `Foo` properties optional within `Foo`. You can make them in the `Explode` type via  `[I in keyof T]+?:` as in e.g. [this](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.3.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHJwBcyIArgLYBG0A3PodaQM5hSgDmDhyCp1TABsIcEAwC+uXGACeABxQBRAB7yh6ACYQAPABUAfMgC8yANYRZ6GMj3IIKyCE0tkoGNGQBpRgQD83vaOEM6u5CBmIOgA7iC+yAHYyADaAJJuIOaW1rYAugDUfqTpDk4ugQF6abnIpCAQAG6eUrx1jdDxbU1QDNJyirYQbCbIqupauhjoBr0I6CDDkGykekNgI9gkyACMEnTIAPQHREIa0RCauHML60tg2ytrG8zIAORwLJqve4fHcKcxC5XeaLNYAJkew1Mm1I2wANMgXu9Pt99kcyOh1v8zkDrqC2ABmSHraESX4nHGXIA)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `Explode` type as:

```
type Explode<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        [key in K]: T[K]
    }
}[keyof T]
```

then `type Test` will become:

```
type Test = {
    a: number;
} | {
    b: string;
} | {
    c: boolean;
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHJwBcyIArgLYBG0A3PodaQM5hSgDmDhyCp1TABsIcEAwC+uXGACeABxQBRAB7yh6ACYQAPABUAfMgC8ORgQDaAaWShkAawiz0MZHoC6pPL14XHs2xBkK083a3dzZCkJPycXNwjpOUU3CDYTZFV1LV0MdAMGXAR0EHTINlI9NLAM7CJSAEYohiA)

Comment: Thanks, but I need a type that allows only one (or none) of the 3 fields to be set. Your example allows more than one field to be set at the same time, e.g. `const test: Test = { a: 1, b: 'asd' };`