# TypeScript: Key in interface from Enum, Optional but at least 1

Tags: typescript, enums, interface

I would like to have an **interface** for an object which has a **userId or a customerId**.
Either one, but one.

The **key** is supposed to be defined **by an enum** (so naming is always the same).

I used this way, from another example:

```
export enum EId {
  userId = 'userId',
  customerId = 'customerId',
}

export type IIdParam = {
  [key in EId]: string;
};

export interface IIdParamString extends IIdParam {
  paramString: string;
}
```

In the end I would like to have this object:

```
  const params: IIdParamString = {
    userId: String('1234'),
    paramString: 'limit',
  };
```

But I get an error: When `[key in EId]` is not optional, it complains it needs userId and customerId and if not optional, neither ...

Maybe that is not the right approach for what I want.
I guess the value in the enum is actually not needed for the key, but I can not better abstract it from the example.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error. Please read [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please share the link of https://www.typescriptlang.org/play of the example.

Comment: I can not write it with less code. If you paste this into a .ts-file, you should get an error like: Property 'customerId' is missing in type '{ userId: string; paramString: string; }' but required in type 'IIdParamString'

Comment: I see, you edited your question. It will result in the error now, indeed. You can use discriminated unions for this. I will post the solution.

Comment: Please let me know if this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69246630/how-to-express-at-least-one-of-the-exisiting-properties-and-no-additional-prope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
export enum EId {
    userId = 'userId',
    customerId = 'customerId',
}

type AtLeastOne<Obj, Keys = keyof Obj> = Keys extends keyof Obj ? Record<Keys, string> : never

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

export type IIdParamString =
    & StrictUnion<AtLeastOne<typeof EId>>
    & {
        paramString: string;
    }

/**
 * Ok
 */
const params: IIdParamString = {
    userId: '1234',
    paramString: 'limit',
};

/**
 * Expected errors
 */
const params2: IIdParamString = {
    paramString: 'limit',
};
const params3: IIdParamString = {
    userId: '1234',
    customerId: 'sdf',
    paramString: 'limit',
};
```

**`AtLeastOne`** - you can find full explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69246630/how-to-express-at-least-one-of-the-exisiting-properties-and-no-additional-prope)

**`StrictUnion`** - you can find full explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753). This utility makes similar trick with `never` which you did.

> Is my approach in general conventional to my problem, to make sure it is either this or that

Yes, your approach is ok. But I recommend you to use discriminated unions. They are also known as `tagged unions`. For instance see [F# discriminated unions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions). As you might have noticed, each union has own tag/flag/marker. It helps compiler to distinguish them.

> Could it be an interface ?
> Unfortunately - no. It could be only type, because `interface` can extends only statically known type. See example:

```js
// An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.
export interface IIdParamString extends StrictUnion<AtLeastOne<typeof EId>> { // error
    paramString: string;
}
```

Regarding your last question, I'm not sure if I understand it.
You can update your question or (the better) option to ask separate.

Comment: Yes. That is exatly what I want and works like a charm. Thank you so much for understanding and solving. I am still so new to TypeScript, that my example, is the most advanced code I can write so far.I know slighly about generics ... I call my self very happy, if you could even add some explanation. Simple question at first: Why is IIdParamString not working as an interface but type?

Comment: And another question: Is my approach in general conventional to my problem, to make sure it is either this or that? Thanks again so much for this amaaaazing help.

Comment: ... could it be an interface. My plan was, that I extend from that intereface some more, which can be implemented into classes ...

Comment: `type` is more flexible than `interface` in this case. Please give me one hour for the explanation

Comment: Sorry, of course. No rush meant. Just got insanly curious and questions arising.

Comment: Just another thought, again no rush intended: Instead of extending a Class from an interface, I would use in the cass  (constrcutor) the type IIdParamString to check if I get, what I want?

Comment: I made an update, let me know if you have further questions. Btw, I have typescript blog https://catchts.com/ , you can find a lot of interesting examples there

Comment: Thanks you so much, that is great helps a lot. As well to broaden my TypeScript hoirzion. I am going through it soon.