# Select only one key type pair from string key - object type pair list in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I've been faced a problem how can pick only one item from key-type list in generic.

And I solve it with dirty way but I hope to write with more good ways.

example) I would like to make dto for users and one user type is selected but others is not.

```js
// here 3 classes
class User { .. }
class IntegrationUser { .. }
class Admin {..}

// and they will be matched with keys
export type UserKeyEntityMap = {
  user: User;
  admin: Admin;
  integration: IntegrationUser;
}

// so user type keys is
type UserKey = keyof UserKeyEntityMap;

export type UserResponseDto {
  [ K in keyof UserKeyEntityMap]: UserKeyEntityMap[K];
}
```

expected working is below:

```
// error
const testEmpty = {} as UserResponseDto; 

// Success
const testOnlyHasUser = { user: {} as User } as UserResponseDto; 

// Success
const testOnlyHasAdmin = { admin: {} as Admin } as UserResponseDto; 

// error
const testHaveUserAndAdmin = { user: {} as User; admin: {} as Admin } as UserResponseDto; 

// error
const testHaveUserAndAdminAndIntegration = { user: {} as User; admin: {} as Admin; integration: IntegrationUser } as UserResponseDto;
```

Here is my dirty solution

```js
// this cannot be passed test case: testHaveUserAndAdmin
export type UserResponseDto =
  Pick<UserKeyEntityMap, 'user'> |
  Pick<UserKeyEntityMap, 'admin'> | 
  Pick<UserKeyEntityMap, 'integration'>;
```

Whatever have a beautiful solution ?

Help me !

Comment: You create new objects above, not set types. I see a syntax error: `',' expected`. It should be like: `{ user: {} as User, admin: {} as Admin }`. About dto creation we have two options: merge all properties ({...properties from user and admin...}) or split by types ({user: new User(), admin: new Admin()})

Comment: @AntonHirov Thank you for your comment. but semicolon(;) is correct  in Typescript Type Object. And I have no saying that is set type. Well, Maybe you misunderstand Javascript.

Comment: @AntonHirov See this : https://flaviocopes.com/typescript-object-destructuring/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [distributive-conditional-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), I think this is exactly what you are looking for. From my experience, this feature is very important when it comes to TS conditional types.

Consider this example:

```js
class User { tag = 'User' }
class IntegrationUser { tag = 'IntegrationUser' }
class Admin { tag = 'Admin' }

// and they will be matched with keys
export type UserKeyEntityMap = {
    user: User;
    admin: Admin;
    integration: IntegrationUser;
}

type Distribute<Dict, Keys extends keyof Dict = keyof Dict> = Keys extends any ? Record<Keys, Dict[Keys]> : never

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

// Record<"user", User> | Record<"admin", Admin> | Record<"integration", IntegrationUser>
type UserResponseDto = StrictUnion<Distribute<UserKeyEntityMap>>

// error
const testEmpty: UserResponseDto = {};

// Success
const testOnlyHasUser: UserResponseDto = { user: {} as User };

// Success
const testOnlyHasAdmin: UserResponseDto = { admin: {} as Admin };

// error
const testHaveUserAndAdmin: UserResponseDto = { user: {} as User, admin: {} as Admin };

// error
const testHaveUserAndAdminAndIntegration: UserResponseDto = { user: {} as User, admin: {} as Admin, integration: {} as IntegrationUser };
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoDaPw)

Usualy, if you want to distribute something - just use `T extends any`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69246630/how-to-express-at-least-one-of-the-exisiting-properties-and-no-additional-prope) similar question/answer

Comment: Thank you for useful answer. but that type is not throwing error for empty, or exclusive one selectoin. example, that type cannot pass testEmpty or testHaveUserAndAdmin. And I have realize Typescript does not yet support well generics as much as Java.

anyway your way is more clear and simple. so Thank you

Comment: @cyan-kinesin don't give up on typescript. See my update

Comment: have a something news ? I can wait for you forever. hmm I changed my thought it is not bad creating DTO per request (and primarily DTO is working like that). Maybe we should wait until Typescript is more advanced

Comment: @cyan-kinesin Hi, I don't know how to solve this problem in other way

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found advanced way that satisfy my question partially.

```js
// this type passes testEmpty, testUser, testAdmin but not on testUserAndAdmin or testUserAndAdminAndIntegration
export type UserResponseDto<K> =
  K extends 'user' ?
  Pick<UserKeyEntityMap, 'user'> :
  K extends 'admin' ?
  Pick<UserKeyEntityMap, 'admin'> :
  K extends 'integration' ?
  Pick<UserKeyEntityMap, 'integration'> :
  never;
```

if you have a more good solution, Please teach me.