# Configure a TypeScript type for an object to have at least 1 of any specific keys

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

This question is kinda difficult for me to explain and thus difficult for me to find a definitive answer for.

I have the below code:

```js
type myType = {
    apple ?: any
    banana ?: any
}

const sample = function(myObject : myType) {
    if (typeof myObject.apple !== 'undefined' || typeof myObject.banana !== 'undefined') {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // This will cause an error!
    }
}

sample({ apple: true }) // This is good
sample({ banana: 'hello world' }) // This is good
sample({ apple: false, banana: 'foo bar' }) // This is good
sample({}) // This is NOT good
sample({ banana: undefined }) // This is NOT good
sample({ taco: 'hello world' }) // This is NOT good
```

I am trying to make a type that can detect the "NOT good" cases

**My Question:** How can I modify `myType` to trigger an error when all of its keys are not set but not when at least 1 of its known keys are set?

---

On a side note: I think I can do the below, but it seems very inelegant and probably a poor programming practice. I would prefer an alternate solution because my real code has dozens of keys and would be more than a little tedious.

```js
type myType_1 = {
    apple : any
    banana ?: any
}
type myType_2 = {
    apple ?: any
    banana : any
}
type myType = myType_1 | myType_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a helper type: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAtiAq5oF4oG8BQVtQIZjABsIAuKAIwHtLjcA7LHc+lsgZ2ACcBLOgcwwBfDBlCQoAeToQJAMwA88AHxRUmbAG0A0lF5QA1hBCVZUeAF0AtAH4yABW4BjfYoA0ULSoBkUO7k7A3LiEikpCGobGphYijpR0HFBsuDBEKFCyAK50joHxABRwEuQAVhC5UGRSMgpwiJBKAJTojNjcpvliECawIMVluQB0+GlQAITIqADk2QAmELK8ELNTUAA+a1BdPUWl5cCDzHQs45NQM3Tzi9Irzeo4DwD0j1AAIpRJlDAQwAAWvAIHoIoBBCGxoPcHthnmZ-mwoAB3biEQhQRy4TLgvB0EGcTiUThjVpQYTCDDJVLEfJoPAEYhkLiZaCCZow+Bw3TwvjUWbklJpakUFjHMhTX6gwgfBEEwgrEmsl7s7jw5VQbmUXkUgU0kb0jLBcHuI6sc6yahCzirFlQNkc1XqzX8qloa221WqgByEngap5fMpEEFxpFUDmCyWs3lNsVdvhXp9Dv92q2uDiovFKKlMrlrpj7rj3t9GqAA)

```
type OneOf<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: Pick<T, K> & Partial<T>
}[keyof T]
```

Note that for this to detect the `sample({ banana: undefined })` case, the type of `banana` must **not** be `any` since `undefined` is assignable to `any`.

Answer (score 0):

[THis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69246630/how-to-express-at-least-one-of-the-exisiting-properties-and-no-additional-prope) question/answer is related, but hot full for your case.

In order to forbid `undefined` value in argument, usually you should just loop through each value and replace each `undefined` with `never`. SInce, it is impossible without type assertion create value which will corespond to `never` in your argument, TS throw an error if it will encounter `undefined`.

See example:

```js
type ReplaceUndefined<Obj> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop] extends undefined ? never : Obj[Prop]
}

type Test = ReplaceUndefined<{ name: undefined }> // {name: never}
```

Next, we need to check whether keys of provided argument match `myType` keys. Usually you just need to use this condition: `keyof Obj extends keyof Source`.

Since we also need simultaneously check for `undefined`, we need combine these checks into one:

```js
type ReplaceUndefined<Obj> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop] extends undefined ? never : Obj[Prop]
}

type Validation<Obj, Source> = keyof Obj extends keyof Source ? ReplaceUndefined<Obj> & Source : never
```

However, this is not the end. We still need to validate empty object. For this check, we can use an example from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69246630/how-to-express-at-least-one-of-the-exisiting-properties-and-no-additional-prope).

Full code:

```js
type myType = {
  apple?: any
  banana?: any
}

type AtLeastOne<Obj, Keys = keyof Obj> = Keys extends keyof Obj ? Pick<Required<Obj>, Keys> : never


type ReplaceUndefined<Obj> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop] extends undefined ? never : Obj[Prop]
}


type Validation<Obj, Source> = keyof Obj extends keyof Source ? AtLeastOne<ReplaceUndefined<Obj> & Source> : never

const sample = function <Obj,>(myObject: myType & Validation<Obj, myType>) {

  if (typeof myObject.apple !== 'undefined' || typeof myObject.banana !== 'undefined') {
    // Do something
  } else {
    // This will cause an error!
  }
}

sample({ apple: true }) // This is good
sample({ banana: 'hello world' }) // This is good
sample({ apple: false, banana: 'foo bar' }) // This is good
sample({}) // error
sample({ banana: undefined }) // error
sample({ taco: 'hello world' }) // error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wy4RZm)

If you are interested in static type validation, you can check my [blog](https://catchts.com/validators)